# how to join more functions in a single windows.load

Tags: javascript, jquery

so im trying to join in screen  width and height functions 
im having a hard time making this simple check work

```
$(window).load(function() 
{
    //alert('loaded');
});
$(window)resize(function() {
    if (($(window).width() > 225) && ($(window).width() < 2000) && ($(window).height() > 330) && ($(window).height() < 2000))
{
    alert('yep');
});
```

Comment: By using `$(document).ready` instead.

Comment: If you cache you vars then you can get rid of the uncomfortable horizontal scroll and save some bits: `if (w>225 && w<2000 && h>330 && h<2000)`.

Comment: var h = $(windows).with();  ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.` before resize

```
$(window).resize
```

instead of

```
$(window)resize
```

And place one more brace of if condition at end

```
 alert('yep');
 }
 });
```

instead of

```
 alert('yep');

 });
```

Comment: i did this, but im on a desktop 1024x1060 and it is still not popping up alert yep. any idea whats wrong?

Comment: @GunrJesra  See this demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/JfydH/show/

Comment: @pXL nothing happens on that jsfiddle

Comment: @GunrJesra See this demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/zK7y2/6/

Comment: @GunrJesra. I replaced `alert` with `console.log` , you will see `yep` on console `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/JfydH/show/

Comment: i still dont get an alert on my desktop, alerts are working but if i try any of your guys greatly appreciated jsfiddle i still dont show yep on my end, i even increment some values and nothing

Comment: but my fiddle is working on my mozilla Firefox .Which browser are you using

Comment: oh great now it does thanks @Ankit